# Delete DropDownList items with empty values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to delete DropDownList items with empty values (in SQL Server, they are signed as NULL). The data source is based on LINQ.

This is the code I've used:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSource1";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "localidad";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "basededatos";

    for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.Items[i].Value == "")
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Remove(DropDownList1.Items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to remove empty strings. This is not the same thing as NULL. You say that you need to solve a problem but you don't say what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've encountered a very typical problem when you are looping `Items` property of controls. First thing to be clarified is properties are **dynamically queried**, which means they are dynamic values, not a static list. Therefore, when you delete some values inside a loop, the `Property` changes. That's why you will encounter awkward situation mention by @Steve.

Another problem in your code is: you are using `DropDownList1.Items.Count` as upper bound as well. This value also gets changed dynamically, and thus results in incomplete traversal of the list.

There are at least 2 ways to complete the task in the right way. The first approach is already mentioned by @Steve, but I would like to provide another way to tackle the problem if you insist on traveling `Items` forward:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < DropDownList1.Items.Count)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.Items[i].Value))
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    } else
    {
        i ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem using a LINQ Where statement, but this code is useful in case the items will be added manually, independently of specific data sources. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not actually checking for nulls, this code will remove both null and empty strings (which are different):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSource1";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "localidad";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "basededatos";

        for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.Items[i].Value))
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Remove(DropDownList1.Items[i]);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I solved my problem using a LINQ Where statement, but this code is useful in case the items will be added _manually_, independently of specific data sources. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, but **they haven't solved my problem because my DropDownList Items come from a DataSource** (in this case, based on LINQ), not being added directly in the HTML code.

I have had to use the SQL clause **WHERE**, which have let me filter items with empty values.

Regards.